# General interval scheduling

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computer-science

We shall start with below problem.

**Problem:** Given a list of classes for student to subscribe for a week:

Math: Monday 1pm-3pm; Wednesday 4pm-6pm
(That means Math class learn from 1pm to 3pm on Monday and from 4pm to 6pm on Wednesday)

History: Tuesday 2pm-3pm;
Wednesday 5pm-7pm

Physic: Tuesday 2pm-4pm; Friday 2pm-8pm
...

If student subcribed to a class, he can't drop any lesson in that subject. And a student can't subscribed to 2 "overlap" classes.

What is maximum number of classes that a student can subscribe?

This problem is general than interval scheduling problem (or activity selection theorem), where each activity consists of unconnected interval of time. So greedy algorithm apply for ISP is not efficient in this case.

I wonder if there is any research in this general case or any result about it? I have tried to find but there was nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, your problem is equivalent to finding the largest independent set in a graph (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory))). So all the research about independent sets applies. It is known to be NP Hard, and even hard to approximate to within a polynomial factor. On the other hand, for bounded degree instances (suppose each class only overlaps with a bounded number of other classes), there is a greedy algorithm that gives an approximation factor of $(\Delta + 2)/3$ if the maximum degree is $\Delta$ (see the wikipedia article for details).

The reduction from the max independent set problem is as follows. Suppose we are given a graph $G$. For every vertex $v$ in $G$ we create a corresponding class $c(v)$. For every edge $(u, v)$ in $G$, we create a lesson for $c(u)$ and $c(v)$ at the same time, and not overlapping with any other lesson. Then a set of classes can be subscribed to if and only if the corresponding vertices in $G$ form an independent set.